# bootstrap withword press integration

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, integration, expand

I have looked online quite abit and cant seem to find an answer and hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am a little familiar with wordpress loops but I have a bootstrap theme with several divs. Is it possible to have a div that calls the wordpress posts that expands once the user clicks? any information I find online is how to build bootstrap wordpress themes. So basically id like a post/news section that does not redirect and opens the content in the same div. I hope that makes sense.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad, but for instance:

1) To use bootstrap you have to add the js and css files using `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_scripts()`, and hook this into the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

2) To manipulate how the post is shown it would mostly be done with CSS and `javascript` or `jquery` to hide or show html elements. Or you can find some suitable widget in jquery-ui or some other library. For the contents,  I think you have two alternatives:

I. to download the post content into the page so the content is there when you decide to show it or not based on user clicks (captured in the javascript).

II. Just download a reference to the post (like the post id) and have an ajax call download the content to be shown, also based, on user clicks.
This alternative is more complex you need to understand how ajax calls are made in worpdress and also add some security measures like a nonce that can be verified by the server. [WP Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to address this issues splitting your tasks in different aspects:

- In terms of design, you want to use or you are using Bootstrap.
- In terms of interaction, you can use CSS and Javascript to achieve that do you want.
- In terms of how WordPress delivery the info you have to use PHP and WordPress functions.

As far as I understand your question, you want to create kind of drop-down menu, where you have a list with your post titles and with the click interaction is going to show the content of the post.

Something like [this](http://panama.primerainfancia.info/category/primera-infancia-en-panama/caracteristicas-generales-de-los-nin%CC%83os-y-las-nin%CC%83as-de-0-a-5-an%CC%83os-de-edad/)

**My advice:**
- You have to understand how the WordPress loop works.
- Be familiar with the Bootstrap elements, in this case with [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) (A combination of CSS and Jquery) 
- Finally, my approach to any problem is created small tasks in this case:

- PHP - WORDPRESS: USE - the_title & the_content
- PHP - CSS - HTML (bootstrap): hide the_content
- Using Bootstrap create the interaction.

Let me know if I'm clear or I did not get your idea.

Comment: Yes, something like that would be perfect, I'm pretty novice to this and it is all new to me but this has given me food for thought! Thank you! :)